# Eclipse console stack trace search very slow with web tool project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, console, trace, eclipse-wtp

whenever an exception occurs and I try to jump to the corresponding class by clicking the link in the standard console it takes very long and eclipse shows in the bottom right corner "Searching...". If I copy the stacktrace to the stack trace console the corresponding class shows up immediately. The console output is produced by apache tomcat using the web tools project.

Is it somehow possible to tell eclipse that it should first search my local classes?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the console stack trace is slow, too.  I often just don't use it.  Instead I just copy the name of the class and call open type on it.

Apologies for the non-answer, but this is the only workaround I could find.